# Foxx/ArangoDB: Typescript

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I would love to develop foxx applications in Typescript.

Can someone point me in the right direction, if this is at all possible?

Thanks!

Cheers,

Gerd

Answer (score 3):

You should check out the [arangodb-typescript-setup](https://github.com/akaztp/arangodb-typescript-setup) library and the associated article [Using Typescript for programming ArangoDB FOXX services](http://devblog.ztp.pt/using-typescript-for-programming-arangodb-foxx-services/).

Comment: I've created a fork including the `@types/arangodb` `@types/joi` and `@types/node` which are missing in the linked repo: [arangodb-typescript-setup](https://github.com/RienNeVaPlus/arangodb-typescript-setup)

Answer (score 0):

this topic has already been covered in another Stackoverflow article:
[ArangoDB Foxx and Clojure script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845520/arangodb-foxx-and-clojure-script/36858853#36858853)

Comment: How so?  The referenced post doesn't really address this question.